# Strict Avalanche Criteria in Sage

Tags: cryptanalysis, s-boxes

Is there any inbuilt functionality in sage to check if any S-Box satisfies [Strict Avalanche Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect#Strict_avalanche_criterion) or not?

Comment: I do not think so, see my answer here on the basics of calculating the SAC table https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60501/strict-avalanche-criterion-sac/60523#60523